# Google no me muestra un mapa insertado en un frame en mi pagina

Tags: google-maps

Tengo la siguiente web en linea: billarentrerriano.com en la seccion salas quiero poner un card para cada sala oficial de la provincia. Dentro de la card de cada sala un mapa, el cual lo obtuve de Google Maps, en la opcion "Compartir e insertar Mapa". Pero si se fijan obtengo los siguiente:

**La página www.google.com está bloqueada
La página www.google.com ha rechazado la conexión.

ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE**
Añado imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿A que se debe y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Probaste en otro navegador?, visité el sitio en Firefox y edge y en ambos se muestran el mapa

Comment: Ya lo solucione, tenia que copiar la direccion embed, donde dice insertar un mapa, estaba poniendo otro enlace